# Google script to create a folder and then create a Google Doc in that folder

Tags: google-apps-script

I have been searching for a simple way to create a folder and then create a Google Doc in that folder.

From what I have seen in other questions, it looks as if there is no easy way to do this, but rather you have to create the folder and then create the document, and then move the document to the folder and then remove it from the root folder. Is there an easier way to do this, or is this just a big error on Google's part to make this easier?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is an easier way to do this.
But I would wrap the whole process in a function.

```
function createDoc(folderID, name) {
  var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderID),
      doc = DocumentApp.create(name),
      id = doc.getId(),
      file = DriveApp.getFileById(id);
  DriveApp.getRootFolder().removeFile(file);
  folder.addFile(file);
  return doc;
}
```

Comment: Yes, this is precisely what I have seen in other questions, and what I find terribly inefficient. Hopefully Google will fix this in the future if there is indeed no other way. On the other hand, what I am looking for, (and what may make this easier) is that we create the folder and then create the Doc in the folder. In your answer you presuppose the folder exists, but my goal is to create it as well.