# Google script API - How to create a google doc in a particular folder

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api, google-docs

Basically this question is giving an answer for what I'd like to do:

[Google script to create a folder and then create a Google Doc in that folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33621879/google-script-to-create-a-folder-and-then-create-a-google-doc-in-that-folder)

But it's 5 years old, and I was wondering if there was an easier way now. In my case I have lots of existing folders and I want to create a particular file in each of them via a script that runs at intervals.

Thx.

EDIT:

Ok, the code below works fine (using a modified sample script 1 in the answer) when the folder 'test folder' is in a shared drive.

```
function testFunction() {
  
  const notesFileName = 'test doc';
  const folderName = 'test folder';
  const query = "title = '" + folderName + "'";
  // Find all folders that match the query.
  var folders = DriveApp.searchFolders(query);
  while (folders.hasNext()) {
    // In all the sub-folders, of each found folder, create a file with the same name.
    var folder = folders.next();
    Logger.log("Found a folder: " + folder);
    var subFolders = folder.getFolders();
    while( subFolders.hasNext() ) {
      var subFolder = subFolders.next();
      Logger.log('Folder id: ' + subFolder.getId());
      const doc = Drive.Files.insert({title: notesFileName, mimeType: MimeType.GOOGLE_DOCS, parents: [{id: subFolder.getId()}]}, null, {supportsAllDrives: true});
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean `runs at intervals` ?

Comment: @marios When you create a google apps script, you can set it up so that it runs every N minutes via a Trigger.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your goal as follows.

- You want to create new Google Document to the specific folders.
- You have a lot of folders you want to create new Google Document. So you want to reduce the process cost of the script.

In this case, I would like to propose to create the new Google Document using Drive API. When Drive API is used, the creation of Google Document to each folder can run with the asynchronous process. The sample script is as follows.

#### Sample script 1:

Before you use this script, [please enable Drive API at Advanced Google services](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced#enable_advanced_services). In this sample script, the new Google Documents are created to the specific folders in a loop.

```
function sample1() {
  const titleOfDocument = "sample document";
  const folderIds = ["### folder ID1 ###", "### folder ID 2 ###",,,];
  const documentIds = folderIds.map(id => Drive.Files.insert({title: titleOfDocument, mimeType: MimeType.GOOGLE_DOCS, parents: [{id: id}]}).id);
  console.log(documentIds)
}
```

- In this script, the created Document IDs are returned.
- If the process time of this script was long in your actual situation, please test the following sample script 2.

#### Sample script 2:

Before you use this script, [please enable Drive API at Advanced Google services](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced#enable_advanced_services). In this sample script, the new Google Documents are created to the specific folders using the batch request of Drive API using a Google Apps Script library. By this, the tasks are run with the asynchronous process.

Please install the Google Apps Script library for using the batch request. [Ref](https://github.com/tanaikech/BatchRequest#how-to-install)

```
function sample2() {
  const titleOfDocument = "sample document";
  const folderIds = ["### folder ID1 ###", "### folder ID 2 ###",,,];
  const requests = {
    batchPath: "batch/drive/v3",
    requests: folderIds.map(id => ({
      method: "POST",
      endpoint: `https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files`,
      requestBody: {name: titleOfDocument, mimeType: MimeType.GOOGLE_DOCS, parents: [id]},
    })),
    accessToken: ScriptApp.getOAuthToken(),
  };
  const result = BatchRequest.EDo(requests); // Using GAS library
  const documentIds = result.map(({id}) => id);
  console.log(documentIds)
}
```

#### Note:

- For above sample scripts, if you want to retrieve the folder IDs under the specific folder, you can also use for `folderIds` as follows.

  ```
    const topFolderId = "### top folder ID ###";
    const folders = DriveApp.getFolderById(topFolderId).getFolders();
    const folderIds = [];
    while (folders.hasNext()) {
      folderIds.push(folders.next().getId());
    }
  ```
- By the way, in the current stage, in order to move the file, you can use [moveTo(destination)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/file#movetodestination). Using this, the script of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33622874) can be modified as follows.

  ```
    function createDoc(folderID, name) {
      var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderID);
      var doc = DocumentApp.create(name);
      DriveApp.getFileById(doc.getId()).moveTo(folder);
      return doc;
    }
  ```

#### References:

- [Files: insert of Drive API v2](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/reference/files/insert)
- [Files: create of Drive API v3](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/create)
- [BatchRequest](https://github.com/tanaikech/BatchRequest)

Comment: Hi, sample script 1 is exactly what I'm looking for, except it's not working. It blows up because it doesn't like the {id: folder.getId()} that I'm passing in. Note, the folders are dynamically found, so I have v3 code that is somewhat complicated that collects the folders that need this file. I'm wondering if that has to do with some v2/v3 conflict. And really, why oh why can't I just use v3 to do this? It's just weird I can't simply use the Folder.createFile() call as documented here: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/folder

Comment: @Jack Thank you for replying. I apologize for the inconvenience and my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand about your current situation from your replying. Because when I tested the sample script 1, no error occurs. I apologize for this. In order to correctly understand about your current situation, can you provide your current whole script for replicating your issue?

Comment: @Jack Because from `Note, the folders are dynamically found, so I have v3 code that is somewhat complicated that collects the folders that need this file.`, I cannot image your current script. This is due to my poor skill. I deeply apologize for this. Can you cooperate to resolve your issue?

Comment: thanks for your help, but how about this: show me the code that shows how you get the folder id's. My code is just doing this: {id: folder.getId()}, and that's blowing up. I get the Folder object from the v3 api, and that code is complicated, since it's looking for the "right" folder to add this file to. The error I get is "File not Found", and it prints the id, and that is indeed the id of the folder.

Comment: @Jack Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand about your replying. But from your replying, I understood that you are not using the same script with my proposed script. So can you provide your current script? If you can do, please add it to your question. By this, I would like to confirm it. If you can cooperate to resolve your issue, I'm glad. Can you cooperate to do it? But if I misunderstood your replying, I apologize.

Comment: Ok, I edited the original with some sample code. Please check it out. Thx.

Comment: @Jack Thank you for replying. I saw your added script. I think that the script works. So I cannot understand about your current issue. I apologize for this. Can I ask you about the detail of your current issue? I would like to try to understand it.

Comment: Ok, edited the question again with the error I'm getting, thx.

Comment: Ok, I think I found the problem. The code above works fine when the folder it finds is in "My Drive", but if the folder is in a SHARED drive, that's when I run into the error. Of course, I need this to be in the shared drive, so any thoughts on how I can get it to work would be much appreciated.

Comment: @Jack Thank you for replying. I couldn't notice that you are using the shared Drive. This is due to my poor skill. I deeply apologize for this. In this case, for your script, please modify `const doc = Drive.Files.insert({title: notesFileName, mimeType: MimeType.GOOGLE_DOCS, parents: [{id: subFolder.getId()}]});` to `const doc = Drive.Files.insert({title: notesFileName, mimeType: MimeType.GOOGLE_DOCS, parents: [{id: subFolder.getId()}]}, null, {supportsAllDrives: true});` and test it again.

Comment: Yay! That did it. Thank you so much.

Comment: @Jack Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved.